# Node JS override standard module

Tags: javascript, node.js

Friend has asked an interesting question and I've tried a few things but to no avail, is there any way to override a Node JS module?

For instance, I want to override the readFile function to use an S3 bucket instead of the filesystem. I.E:

```
var fs = require('fs');

fs.readFile('my_text_file.txt', ...);
```

Actually runs something like this

```
FileSystem.readFile = function () {
    // Connect to S3 and retrieve remote file
}
```

I've tried the prototype but it seems they've set up native modules without the `__proto__` object, they don't have a `.constructor` property that means anything to anyone.

I've thought about using [Nodes VM](http://nodejs.org/api/vm.html) but this is too strict as I want the user to be able to install modules via `npm` and use them.

The closest I've actually come is creating a new module (since I can't put a file named `fs.js` in my `node_modules` folder and require it; it just gets ignored) and just hard-setting the values of `fs` to what I want but this isn't quite right, I want the user to be using `require('fs')` and use my custom function.

Is this at all possible without compiling my own version of Node JS?

Comment: I haven't worked with node.js so this might not work at all. You could try to see what function declares `FileSystem` and then use that as a prototype for your custom object ("subclass" it). MyFS={FileSystem.call(this);};MyFs.prototype=new FileSystem(); Or use something like goog.base and goog.inherit to create a subclass that can call it's "parent" functions and deals with parameters passed to the constructor: http://docs.closure-library.googlecode.com/git/closure_goog_base.js.html Note that badse uses `arguments.callee.caller` wich doesn't work in ecma 5 strict so you have to re write that.

Comment: Good article about goog.base and goog.inherits is here: http://bolinfest.com/essays/googbase.html

Comment: I made `FileSystem` up for illustrative purposes, the modules don't have a `__proto__` object and thus no constructor. The closest I've gotten is to directly set properties on the object and including another script but I want to `require('fs')` and it have my custom functionality

Comment: Yea, I just checked out fs.js and doesn't look like node.js uses constructor functions or at least I can't find it.

Answer (score 13):

I feel obliged to strongly warn you against overriding native functions. That being said, this will work:

`main.js:`

```
var fs = require('fs'),
    oldReadFile = fs.readFile;

fs.readFile = function (filename, options, callback) {
  console.log('hey!');
  oldReadFile(filename, options, callback)
};

var other = require('./other');
other.test();
```

`other.js:`

```
var fs = require('fs');

exports.test = function () {
  fs.readFile('./main.js', {encoding: 'utf8'}, function (err, data) {
    console.log(err, data);
  });
};
```

You'll need to wrap your user's script with your own to first override what you want.

Comment: I know, I wouldn't personally. Not at least without `vm` but it's an interesting question. This however is the same as what I've tried already and isn't quite what he wants.

Comment: @Laurent any particular reason to avoid overriding native functions? I am planning to do something similar to override database reads and writes.