# Logging in node.js to a file, without another module

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm running a node application as a daemon. When debugging the daemon, I need to see the output, so I'd like to redirect stdout and stderr to a file.

I'd expect I can just reassign `stdout` and `stderr` like in Python or C:

```
fs = require('fs');
process.stdout = fs.openSync('/var/log/foo', 'w');
process.stderr = process.stdout;
console.log('hello');
```

When I run the script directly, "hello" is printed to the console! Of course when I run in the background, I see output neither on the console (of course) or in `/var/log/foo`.

I don't want or need sophisticated logging. I just need to see the builtin messages that node already provides.

Comment: The whole point of Node.js is to use another module.

Comment: The other module hooks into node somehow. I want to know how, so I can do it myself.

Comment: Read its source code.

Answer (score 1):

The `console` object grabs a reference to `process.stdout` and `stderr` when it is first created.
(you can see this in the [source](https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/master/lib/console.js#L107)).

Re-assigning them later does not affect `console`.

The usual way to redirect these streams is to launch the process with the streams redirected.

Alternatively, you can overwrite the `console` methods and make them write to your file instead.

Answer (score 0):

Similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17074200/node-js-override-standard-module), you can overwrite `process.stdout.write` which is [called](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4976466/difference-between-process-stdout-write-and-console-log-in-node-js) from `console.log`.

```
var fs = require('fs');
var oldWrite = process.stdout.write;

process.stdout.write = function (d) {
    fs.appendFileSync('./foo', d);
    oldWrite.apply(this, arguments);
};

console.log('hello');
```